# Constructor is Underfined

Tags: java

I am getting an error saying my constructor Book(String, int) is undefined in my Dictionary class. I check everything else and try to redo my programs still has an error. Any solutions of fixing this issue?

Book Class:

```
public class Book{
    private String author;
    private int numPages;

    public Book(int code, String title, double price, int quantity, String author, int numPages){
        this.author = author;
        this.numPages = numPages;
    }

    //Getters
    public String getAuthor(){
        return this.author;
    }
    public int getNumPages(){
        return this.numPages;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setAuthor(String author){
        this.author = author;
    }
    public void setNumPages(int numPages){
        this.numPages = numPages;
    }

    //toString
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String outputBookDes = "";
        outputBookDes += "Author: "+ this.author;
        outputBookDes += "Number Pages: "+ this.numPages;
        return outputBookDes;
    }
}
```

Dictionary Class:

```
public class Dictionary extends Book{
private String language;
private int numDefinitions;

public Dictionary(String author, int numPages, String language, int numDefinitions){
    super(author,numPages);
    this.language = language;
    this.numDefinitions = numDefinitions;
}

// Getters
public String getLanguage(){
    return this.language;
}
public int getNumDefinitions(){
    return this.numDefinitions;
}

//Setters
public void setLanguage(String language){
    this.language = language;
}
public void setNumDefinitions(int numDefinitons){
    this.numDefinitions = numDefinitions; 
}

//Ratio method
public double getRatio(){
    double ratioTotal = this.numDefinitions / getNumPages();
    return ratioTotal;
}
```

}

Comment: Well, Book(String, int) is undefined. You only have a Book(int code, String title, double price, int quantity, String author, int numPages) constructor.

Comment: The "Dictionary" class in your post has the same code as the Book class

Comment: Eran is right, and btw your Dictionary code is actually the Book code.

Answer (score 2):

As you are calling

```
super(author,numPages);
```

in child class Dictionary,
you need to define another constructor in Book class like,

```
public Book(String author,int numPages) {
     this.author = author;
     this.numPages = numPages;
}
```

to get this error solved.

Comment: if you find this helpful, kindly accept this as answer, and upvote so that it can be benefited to others in future.

Answer (score 0):

according to your only constructor:

```
public Book(int code, String title, double price, int quantity, String author, int numPages)
```

In your main method try:

```
Book book = new Book(12, "title", 34d, 56, "author", 78);
```

instead of:

```
Book book = new Book("34", 56);
```